# How can I get in code the store of certificate, that is showed in Adobe Reader?

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, adobe, x509certificate

soo I'm trying to get the digital ID that is showed in Adobe Reader to sign a document.

This digital ID's:
[image]

How can I get this store in code? I've looked in Certificates - Current User and they are there:

[image]

But when I try to get this in the code, it comes empty, with this code:

```
  X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

 store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
```

This code should do the trick, but no, it comes empty, I've seen in the other store in code(CertificateAuthority,Root,etc) and they have .cert files. But on "My" store is empty...

So anyone have any sugestion of what I'm doing wrong or a solution for this problem? Thanks in advance.

**Edit1: So someone said my question was not clear, so what I want is to get the store value in code for the certificates inside the "Personal" folder.**

Comment: Not much of clarity in your question, please rephrase what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @BharatVasant I've updated my question, hope you can help